# Putting stuff in my view controller's viewDidUnload doesn't have any effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, viewdidunload

There's a `UIViewController` method `-(void)viewDidUnload`. I tried putting `NSLog("unloaded");` in there to see when the view is unloaded, but nothing was printed to the console.

Where do I put my code, so that before a view unloads I can perform an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using storyboard or not?

Have you tried any of this methods

```
 -(void) viewWillUnload{}
```

or

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{}
```

If you are using storyboards the one that will that usually performs is viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the viewDidUnload documentation, you see that it's related to low memory conditions and **may** be called to help with that.  There is also a viewWillUnload that get's called before the view is released.  It's also related to low memory.

If you're only interested in when the view is no longer seen, there are will/did disappear methods.